# Data entry from a scanned hand written form

Tags: software-rec

I have scanned forms which need to be filled out (by hand). This information needs to be manipulated and analysed in excel (or another database). I can organise for the forms to be tick boxes and boxes for some text but what software can analyse this?

Comment: Are you looking for [OCR software](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-5-free-ocr-software-tools-to-convert-your-images-into-text-nb/)? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Please also add the operating system...

Comment: And also the size of your business/company.  The software provided will vary greatly based on that because of the software's price...

Answer (score 0):

Look into [OMR software](http://www.google.com/search?q=software+to+read+checkboxes&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=#pq=software+to+read+checkboxes+scanned&hl=en&cp=5&gs_id=1a&xhr=t&q=OMR+software&qe=T01SIHM&qesig=ZvvTZesUteHblU626kB09A&pkc=AFgZ2tkxTwZn_CqQCoMqSb30HODVqFeUrpnArmel8EOplQvY6SyK39KOBAyV720ti79lFi_3p8ExS-iwB0kEFWiWqS7bsKP2Uw&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=active&rls=com.microsoft:en-us%3AIE-SearchBox&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=OMR+s&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=422aca6f1b1d5ac1&biw=1280&bih=881)  Google ranked [Remark](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.visionshape.com%2FremarkOMR.htm&ei=blFmTpH6D_TC0AGt7bScCg&usg=AFQjCNF7H5o6ujgfy-OIXUBRYVhHoZis-A&sig2=WC9bjoe0P0Nkryv1Xww3_A) pretty high, so I think it'd be great.

Are you looking for soemthing free?

Comment: Not nessesarily. Thanks for the feedback, not really sure where to start....